# Sound Problems with LXDE (trusty) running through Crouton on ASUS flip (ARMv7 chip)

Tags: 14.04, alsa, lxde, arm, crouton

UPDATED x2 (further reduced errors somehow)

Ok, so I have installed LXDE via crouton and have functioning sound for media playback through VLC. I was hoping to be able to run Audacity (which I believe has basic ARM support) however any attempt to open the programme now gives this :

```
(trusty)itiwid@localhost:~$ audacity

(process:29835): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(process:29835): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(process:29835): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(process:29835): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
FATAL: cannot locate cpu MHz in /proc/cpuinfo
```

Any attempt to load another programme that may utilise the microphone - I have tried GUVCVIEW and QARECORD - gives I think identical output

Any suggestions gratefully received

Thanks

Comment: in case of use (trusty)itiwid@localhost:~$ ls /usr/bin | grep alsa
alsa_in
alsa_out
alsaloop
alsamixer
alsaucm

Comment: Install pulseaudio and lame mp3.
That should help some.
The Lubuntu does not come with pulseaudio.  Skype will not work without it.  I used to be on Lubuntu but I am now on mate which might be a better option for you too.  It might be available for your hardware and has a similar memory footprint.  You can also install pulse audio volume control.  I had a problem with recording kazam until I installed this one.  remember to plus one my comment.

Comment: Pulse was installed; I should have said so.  I thought lame was merely and MP3 encoder? I'll have a look into MATE. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Lubuntu to release 16.04. Audacity is now functioning correctly.

Comment: Nice that you found a solution. Don't forget to accept your answer after the delay of two days to mark your question as solved. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Have you already read the [tour] btw?

Comment: Thanks, not sure about functioning correctly though. I am now having problems with the headphone jack and terminal still fires out a bunch of problems before audacity finally loads, but load it does, and it does record. Also, not sure that LXDE via crouton is the same thing as LUBUNTU ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm the wrong guy to ask, I was just processing the review queue where your answer showed up because it was so short. However, if you have a slightly different follow-up question now, please post it as new question. You can include a link to this one for reference if necessary.